# Closed geodesics on $O^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

I'm reading a snapshot of what modern mathematics looks like: [Closed geodesics on surfaces and Riemannian manifolds](https://imaginary.org/sites/default/files/snapshots/snapshots-2017-005.pdf).

Define$$ O^2:=E^1 \times E^1 $$ where $$ E^1:= \big\{(u,v)\in\Bbb R^{2+}:\log^2(u)+\log^2(v)=1\big\}. $$

Here $\Bbb R^{2+}$ is equipped with the metric $ds^2=\frac{du^2}{u^2}+\frac{dv^2}{v^2}.$

> How can one find the closed geodesics on $O^2?$ (not including meridian and longitude geodesics).

Credits to @robjohn for these:

[image]

[image]

I know that there must be at least one closed geodesic, and I think there could be infinitely many closed geodesics due to a theorem:

Theorem 1: (Gromoll–Meyer, Sullivan–Vigué-Poirrier) Any Riemannian manifold whose rational cohomology ring is generated by at least two elements contains infinitely many distinct closed geodesics.

Also the meridian and longitude geodesics on $O^2$ are (under a coordinate change) equivalent to the meridian and longitude geodesics on $T^2$ (torus). Could this be the case for all the geodesics? That is, could all the geodesics on $O^2$ be related by a coordinate change to the geodesics on $T^2?$

Comment: In order to calculate whether or not the geodesics on $O^2$ are the same as those on $T^2$, you first need to find the metric on both of these surfaces. Then find the diffeomorphism that maps $O^2$ onto $T^2$ and see if it is an isometry. If this is the case, geodesics will be mapped to geodesics and the preimage of a geodesic will be a geodesic. I suspect this is not the case, since $T^2$ and $O^2$ definitely don't look like they would be isometric.

Comment: why does the answer say that they are isometric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand this question. This space is just the torus $T^2,$ and so has the usual complement of geodesics.

Comment: I thought it was geometrically different than the torus?

Comment: @geocalc33 Remember, a curve has no metric - it does not matter how you draw it in the plane.

Comment: so I would need to impose a metric on $O^2$ in order to distinguish it from $T^2?$ I see that topologically they are the same

Comment: From the statement, it seems to have the product metric, which means it is isometric to $T^2.$

Comment: I don't understand. How can the shape (image provided above) have the same geodesics as $T^2$?

Comment: I am not sure what the thing you drew is, but there is only one product metric on the torus.

Comment: Did you see that, $\Bbb R^{2+}$ is equipped with the metric $ds^2=\frac{du^2}{u^2}+\frac{dv^2}{v^2}.$?

Comment: @geocalc33 Fascinating. And?

Comment: oh I think I need to provide the parametrization or algebraic equation of the thing I drew. I understand now